# Getting menu items in a wordpress site with javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api

I'm trying to see if I can query the [wordpress API](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_APIs) to get all of the items in the menu of the site using Javascript.

I can see that there is a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656929/how-to-get-menu-items-in-wordpress) on how to do this in php but I don't know how to translate this to javascript as it seems to be using the internal wordpress PHP API.

There is a [great library here](https://github.com/Automattic/wpcom.js) and I can see that with the following code I can query the site:

```
var site = Site('<id>', WPCOM);
site.get(function(err, info){
  // `info` data object
});
```

But I don't know how to query the menu items or if this is at all possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the rep to put this link in a comment.  I have not used it and don't know if it will do what you need but how about this page: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-api-menus/

Since I am posting as an answer, here is some info from that page:

```
This plugin extends the WordPress JSON REST API with new routes for WordPress registered menus.

The new routes available will be:

       /menus list of every registered menu.
       /menus/<id> data for a specific menu.
       /menu-locations list of all registered theme locations.
       /menu-locations/<location> data for menu in specified menu in theme location.
```

I also found this similar post on wordpress.stackexchange: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209381/get-wp-navigation-menu-from-rest-api-v2.  It ends up pointing to the same 'wp-api-menus/' link.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was after.